# long table exceeds margin

Tags: header-footer, margins, columns

I have two issues with this table. first, it exceeds the margin of the paper. second, I want the  column headers (ARMA, ARCH,  Sanctions, SIGMA2) nice-looking ( bold, etcccc)

Here are my suggestions :

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{xparse} 
\usepackage{siunitx} % centering in tables
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsthm} 
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{cuted}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}       

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htbp]\centering
  \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Within Sectors Within Years}
  \begin{tabular}{l*{10}{c}}
  \hline\hline
      &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}         \\
 \hline

 \alpha  &    0.002\sym{**} &  0.002\sym{**}& 0.000&0.000& -0.000& -0.000 &-0.002 &-0.002 &-0.000& -0.000 \\

      &(0.001) &(0.001)&  (0.001)&(0.001) & (0.001)&(0.001)&  (0.003)&  (0.003)&  (0.001) &  (0.001) \\
 \hline
 ARMA    & &   &   &   &  &  &    & &   &     \\

 \phi    &  -0.099\sym{**} &   -0.093\sym{*}& & &  & & & &&  \\
    &  (0.050)&  (0.053)  &  &    &    & & & &  &    \\

  \theta     &  &  &  0.032  &  0.020    &   &   &    &   &   &  \\
      &  &   &  (0.062) &  (0.059)   &   &   &    &   &   &                  \\
  \hline

 ARCH      &   & &  & &  & &  & & &    \\


\Theta  &   -0.022         &   -0.029         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
      &  (0.026)         &  (0.027)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
 \omega   &                  &                  &    0.027         &    0.018         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
      &                  &                  &  (0.046)         &  (0.040)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
 \omega_{3}  &                  &                  &    0.046         &    0.038         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
      &                  &                  &  (0.050)         &  (0.044)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
  \beta  &    0.000\sym{***}&                  &    0.000\sym{***}&                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
      &  (0.000)         &                  &  (0.000)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
 \hline
Sanctions       & & & & & & & &  &  &   \\


  Black Monday&                  &    0.250\sym{*}  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
      &                  &  (0.134)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
 Debt Debate&                  &   -1.022         &                  &                &                &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
      &                  &  (0.817)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
Mini Crash&                  &                  &                  &   -0.278\sym{*}  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
      &                  &                  &                  &  (0.149)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
  f15minicrash&                  &                  &                  &   -2.088         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
      &                  &                  &                  &(484.849)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
 f13minicrash&                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   -0.678\sym{***}&                  &                  &                  &                  \\
      &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &  (0.163)         &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
Currency sanctions &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   -0.380\sym{**} \\
      &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &  (0.169)         \\
 Constant  &                  &   -8.783\sym{***}&                  &   -9.088\sym{***}&                  &   -7.909\sym{***}&                  &                  &                  &   -9.313\sym{***}\\
      &                  &  (0.112)         &                  &  (0.147)         &                  &  (0.096)         &                  &                  &                  &  (0.108)         \\
\hline
 SIGMA2    &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
 Constant  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    0.000\sym{***}&                  &    0.001\sym{***}&    0.001\sym{***}&    0.000\sym{***}&                  \\
      &                  &                  &                  &                  &  (0.000)         &                  &  (0.000)         &  (0.000)         &  (0.000)         &                  \\
\hline
\(N\)     &      352         &      352         &      351         &      351         &      248         &      248         &      258         &      258         &      256         &      256         \\
 aic       &-2034.495         &-2034.309         &-2234.085         &-2234.576         &-1306.025         &-1316.662         &-1009.682         &-1009.682         &-1687.303         &-1689.566         \\
bic       &-2019.041         &-2011.127         &-2214.781         &-2207.551         &-1298.998         &-1306.122         &-1002.576         &-1002.576         &-1680.213         &-1678.930         \\
 \hline\hline
 \multicolumn{11}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{11}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<.10\), \sym{**} \(p<.05\), \sym{***} \(p<.01\). The $\phi$ are AR coefficients, the $\theta$ are MA coefficients, the $\omega$ are ARCH coefficients, and the $\sigma$ are GARCH coefficients. $\alpha$ is the constant for mean equation and  is $\beta$ the constant for the variance equation. The Ljung-Box $Q$-Statistics for the $40$ lags of the standardized residuals $(Q40)$ and the squared standardized residuals $(Q40^2)$ are presented in the bottom panel.}\\
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

  \end{document}
```

MY OUTPUT :n[image]

Comment: `\multicolumn{11}{l}` is forced to be one line, instead set it as a paragraph _after_ the tabular

Comment: Pleas make your example compilable. For example `\alpha`, `\phi` etc. must be used in math mode so need `$ $` around it. Make sure it compiles without errors before posting it here.

Comment: Hmmm.... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options again?

Comment: @Rmano thanks i have seen that before.. i need solution to my own problem